# EF Core Bulk Extensions: Index was out of range on BulkInsert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I am getting the following error while using bulk insert from EF core bulk extensions:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. (Parameter 'index')    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.TableInfo.UpdateEntitiesIdentity[T](IList`1
>   entities, IList`1 entitiesWithOutputIdentity)    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.TableInfo.LoadOutputData[T](DbContext context,
>   IList`1 entities)    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.SqlBulkOperation.Merge[T](DbContext context,
>   IList`1 entities, TableInfo tableInfo, OperationType operationType,
>   Action`1 progress)    at
>   EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert[T](DbContext
>   context, IList`1 entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1 progress)
>   at MyProject.Data.Repository.Repository`1.CreateRange(List`1 entities)

I have a parent entity and child entity. What I am trying to do is, first bulk insert parent and then assign Ids generated for parent to their children. Then bulk insert children.

`CreateRange` method:

```
public List<T> CreateRange(List<T> entities)
{
    var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig { PreserveInsertOrder = true, SetOutputIdentity = true };
    _dbContext.BulkInsert(entities, bulkConfig);
    return entities;
}
```

Bulk insert code:

```
// Index parents. (Since PreserveInsertOrder = true is set.)
parents.ForEach(x => x.Id = parents.IndexOf(x) + 1);
_parentRepository.CreateRange(parents);

// parent-child relation mapping.
parents.ForEach(x => x.Children.ToList().ForEach(y => y.ParentId = x.Id));

var children = parents.SelectMany(x => x.Children).ToList();
// Index children. (Since PreserveInsertOrder = true is set.)
children.ForEach(x => x.Id = children.IndexOf(x) + 1);
_childRepository.CreateRange(children);
```

It's not always possible to reproduce this issue. I am not able to identify the condition for reproducing this issue.

Comment: `parents.IndexOf(x) - parents.Count` do you really want to assign negative key values? Because, `parents.Count` will be greater than `parents.IndexOf(x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception occurs due to the Ids being assigned before the bulk insert operation is conflicting with the Ids already existing in the database. The solution is to use Ids that are not in the database. For example, negative numbers. This can still preserve the order of insertion since what matters is the relative order between entities within the list to be inserted.

The modified code:

```
// Index parents with non-conflict keys. (Since PreserveInsertOrder = true is set.)
parents.ForEach(x => x.Id = parents.IndexOf(x) - parents.Count);
_parentRepository.CreateRange(parents);

// parent-child relation mapping.
parents.ForEach(x => x.Children.ToList().ForEach(y => y.ParentId = x.Id));

var children = parents.SelectMany(x => x.Children).ToList();
// Index children with non-conflict keys. (Since PreserveInsertOrder = true is set.)
children.ForEach(x => x.Id = children.IndexOf(x) - children.Count);
_childRepository.CreateRange(children);
```